# React Native ViewPager with a KeyboardAvoidingView as parent doesn't keep the keyboard up - iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

When I use the `ViewPager` from `react-native-community/viewpager` with a `KeyboardAvoidingView` and the style of `ViewPager` is `flex:1` and the behaviour of KeyboardAvoidingView is `padding` the keyboard can't keep up.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex: 1}} behavior="padding">
    <ViewPager
      {...viewPagerProps}
      ref={viewPagerRef}
      scrollEnabled={false}
      keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
      style={[{flex: 1, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red'}, style]}
      onPageScroll={Animated.forkEvent(onPageScroll, _onPageScroll)}
    />
    {_renderBottomControls()}
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

**_renderBottomControls()**

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', padding: 8}}>
    <Transitioning.View
      transition={transition}
      ref={transitionBackButtonRef}>
      {currentPage !== 0 && (
        <Button mode="text" compact onPress={_onPressPrevious}>
          Voltar
        </Button>
      )}
    </Transitioning.View>

    <Button mode="contained" disabled={!isValid} onPress={_onPressNext}>
      {isLastPage ? 'Concluir' : 'Continuar'}
    </Button>
  </SafeAreaView>
```

[image: GIF showing de issue]

Answer (score 2):

The fix for this was not obvious and I hope the developers will put this in the documentation

The view pager needs to be position absolute

`<ViewPager style={{position: 'absolute'}}/>`

Also if the screen is now being hiden by the keyboard, wrap the viewpager in a `KeyboardAvoidingView`